# href link from svg object

Tags: php, svg

I created SVG rectangle with the text "My Text" in it. 
I'd like to add clickable link to text "My Text" using href attributes (or something else) to redirect site to another php file. 
But, I always get only the rectangle with text "My Text" without a link.

```
<?php
   echo "<svg width='1100' height='1620'>";
   echo "<rect x='450' y='30' width='200' height='30' style='fill:white stroke:black;stroke-width:2'></rect>";
   $my_text = "My Text"; 
   echo "<text x='473'  y='51' font-family='Verdana' font-size='18' fill='black' > <a href='index.php'>$my_text</a></text>";
   echo "</svg>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment (2016-11-12) browsers are not consistent on this isssue.

Certain contemporary browsers will (and should) understand `href`:

```
<svg width="1100" height="1620">
<rect x="450" y="30" width="200" height="30" style="fill:white; stroke:black; stroke-width:2;"></rect>
<text x="473" y="51" font-family="Verdana" font-size="18" fill="black" >
<a href="index.php">My Text</a>
</text>
</svg>
```

Others will only understand the XML `xlink:href` syntax:

```
<svg width="1100" height="1620">
<rect x="450" y="30" width="200" height="30" style="fill:white; stroke:black; stroke-width:2;"></rect>
<text x="473" y="51" font-family="Verdana" font-size="18" fill="black" >
<a xlink:href="index.php">My Text</a>
</text>
</svg>
```

To ensure maximum cross-browser compatibility, use (for now):

```
<svg width="1100" height="1620">
<rect x="450" y="30" width="200" height="30" style="fill:white; stroke:black; stroke-width:2;"></rect>
<text x="473" y="51" font-family="Verdana" font-size="18" fill="black" >
<a xlink:href="index.php>
<a href="index.php">My Text</a>
</a>
</text>
</svg>
```

---

## Further Reading about XML xlink: - and its deprecation in SVG2:

**See:** [Mozilla Developer Network: xlink:href](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href)